# Write a trigger for dbms

Tags: sql, database, plsql, rdbms

I don't know what to do.

Write a trigger that not allowing to apply for job if bachelor degree is not BCA or BCA
percentage is less than 60.
Use following table. Applicant(Name, BachelorDegree, PassingYear, Percentage)

Comment: please show use 1. what you have done so far? 2. input table/data 3. expected output

Comment: Also: for **what** RDBMS is this? Triggers are **highly** vendor-specific - a trigger for `oracle` won't be compatible with `sql-server` or `postgresql` - which RDBMS are you targetting??

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the Trigger is not needed here.

You can use the `CHECK` constraint as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE Applicant
ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK (BachelorDegree <> 'BCA' OR Percentage > 60);
```

If you really want to have a trigger then you can use the `TRIGGER` with the `WHEN` clause as follows (This solution assumes that when the `percentage` or `BachelorDegree` is null, it should allow adding data. If this is not your requirement then you can add the conditions accordingly in `WHEN` clause):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER APPLICANTS_TRG BEFORE
    INSERT OR UPDATE OF BACHELORDEGREE, PERCENTAGE ON APPLICANT
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ( NEW.BACHELORDEGREE = 'BCA' AND NEW.PERCENTAGE < 60 )
BEGIN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Percentage must be above 60 for BCA applicants');
END;
/
```

Comment: Obviously the question is an exercise from a homework assignment, which is why it's asking for a trigger.

Comment: A better way of using check constraints would be apply a separate constraint to each column, which would lead to clearer errors. Likewise, for a trigger solution it would be better to validate each column separately, and hurl a focused exception.